# multibranch if or switch statement in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I'm a little unsure of how to do this in coffeescript.  Right now we have some code that sets a variable conditionally:

`myCar.sparkPlug= options.sparkPlug if options.sparkPlug?`

However, it's now possible the `sparkPlug` property may be initialized with another value:

`myCar.sparkPlug = options.glowPlug if options.glowPlug?`

What I want to do is set `myCar.sparkPlug` to the value of `options.SparkPlug`, but if `options.glowPlug` exists, use that.  (It's possible the `options` object will have both a `sparkPlug` and `glowPlug` property.)

I can do it by listing the two lines of code above in order, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, this is what You need:

```
myCar.sparkPlug = if options.glowPlug? then options.glowPlug else options.SparkPlug
```

or more complex:

```
myCar.sparkPlug = if options.glowPlug? then options.glowPlug else (if options.SparkPlug? then options.SparkPlug)
```

Comment: Thank you.  What would be ideal is something like `if options.glowPlug? then options.glowPlug else if options.sparkPlug? then options.sparkPlug`  (I'll check if that's valid syntax.)

Comment: @jkj2000 yes, it's valid. look at answer